# Liferay DXP JSF portlet logging in custom file and location

Tags: logging, liferay, liferay-7

The JSF portlet's class is the GenericFacesPortlet (which means not the MVCPortlet) and slf4j is used.
I tried the resources/META-INF/portlet-log4j.xml (with dtd), but I cannot achieve logging in custom file and location.

Any hints would be appreciated, for example a running example using the GenericFacesPortlet, too.
Liferay patch level is 7.1.10.fp14

I'd like to log for for one category (custom AuditLog class in a component, using slf4j and used by multiple portlets) in for example liferay/logs/auditlog oder liferay/tomcat/logs/auditlog

The portlets are registered and known in osgi (the component is just a jar dependency a.t.m.)

Code:

```
org.slf4j.Logger _logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFacytory.getLogger(Classname)
_logger.info("hello world");
```

**Update**

I don't post this as an answer, because for me adding files to ROOT is just a workaround.

Using a `tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/portal-log4j-ext.xml` works.

Custom file appender in custom directory under tomcat/logs.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

<appender name="myAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <param name="FileNamePattern" value="${catalina.base}/logs/my-custom-location/my-custom-logfile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.zip" />
        <param name="ActiveFileName" value="${catalina.base}/logs/my-custom-location/my-custom-logfile.log" />
    </rollingPolicy>

    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy/MM/dd HH\:mm\:ss} %-5p [%t][%c{1}:%L] %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="my.custom.package">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="myAppender" />
</logger>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Just asking for code is off-topic on stackoverflow (check [help/on-topic]), but you might find help modifying your existing code (just make it minimal)

Comment: This is an architectural question containing the relevant details. It's about configuring logging to achieve custom some custom portlet logfile name an location.

Comment: How about using Liferay logging system com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.LogFactoryUtil ?

Comment: Ouch - "Audit" pointed my brain into the direction of the Liferay Audit Framework - now I understand. A better fit would still be: "This is what I do", "This is what I observe (e.g. wrong output location", "This is what I've tried", "This is what I expect". In contrast, "please point me to example code" is quite generic.

Comment: @iLyas, thanks, I'll check it out but I guess it is also just logging into default log files, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this the other day and was able to make it work with the path src/main/webapp/META-INF/module-log4j-ext.xml rather than src/main/resources/META-INF/module-log4j-ext.xml

Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <category name="com.liferay.faces.demos.applicant.alloy.facelets.mbf">
        <priority value="DEBUG" />
    </category>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: Hi Neill, thanks. Currently I managed to do it by putting a portal-log4j-ext.xml in ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF, but I'll give your suggestion a try since I don't like hooking. Regards, gun

Comment: doesn't work for me, maybe our osgi- or other config isn't complete enough. I'll stick to ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/portal-log4j-ext a.t.m. Regards, gun

Comment: I updated the answer with example contents for module-log4j-ext.xml that worked for me.

Comment: thanks neil, but the main goal is a custom file in a custom location, and this a.t.m. only works for me as described in my question update.